# How to properly extend a TypeScriot Interface? There should be only 1 child

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using a private company library for Accordion. I am using TS 4.6.4 and React 17.
According to the docs it works if there are multiple children:

```
question
answer
question
answer
question
answer
```

However I get the error:

```
This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactChild | undefined', but multiple children were provided.
```

This error is showing up on:

```
  <StyledAccordion onChange={onChange}>
      <dt>Question(SBTi)?</dt>
      <div>answer </div>
      <dt>Question(SBTi)?</dt>
      <div>answer </div>
```

StyledAccordion is a styled component:

```
export const StyledAccordion = styled(Accordion)``
```

The interface of this component includes:

```
export interface AccordionProps {
....
....
    children?: ReactChild;
....
....
```

Thus I am trying to extend this interface to make it support multiple children by TypeScript... I think the typescript was not well developed here...

I am trying this way:

```
interface MultipleChildrenAccordion extends AccordionProps {
  children?: React.ReactChild[]|React.ReactNode|undefined;
}
```

However I am getting:

```
Interface 'MultipleChildrenAccordion' incorrectly extends interface 'AccordionProps'.
  Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
    Type 'ReactChild[] | ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ReactChild | undefined'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ReactChild | undefined'.ts(2430)
```

Your help to make it accept multiple children would be really appreciated...

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**
I've update the type with:

```
type MultipleChildrenAccordion = Omit<AccordionProps, 'children'> & {
  children?: React.ReactChild[]|React.ReactNode|undefined;
}
```

However now on `<StyledAccordion onChange={onChange}>` I get:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { onChange?: ((accordion: AccordionAPI, openItems: number[]) => void) | undefined; ref?: Ref<AccordionAPI> | undefined; key?: Key | null | undefined; ... 8 more ...; iconProps?: IconProps | undefined; } & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; onChange: (() => void) | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ onChange?: ((accordion: AccordionAPI, openItems: number[]) => void) | undefined; ref?: Ref<AccordionAPI> | undefined; key?: Key | null | undefined; ... 8 more ...; iconProps?: IconProps | undefined; }'.
      Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
        Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type '(ReactChild & (string | number | boolean | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | ReactChild[] | null)) | undefined'.
          Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> & ReactChild[]'.
            Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>': type, props, key
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<ForwardRefExoticComponent<AccordionProps & RefAttributes<AccordionAPI>>, any, Omit<AccordionProps, "children"> & { ...; }, never, ForwardRefExoticComponent<...>, ForwardRefExoticComponent<...>>): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; onChange: (() => void) | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ onChange?: ((accordion: AccordionAPI, openItems: number[]) => void) | undefined; ref?: Ref<AccordionAPI> | undefined; key?: Key | null | undefined; ... 8 more ...; iconProps?: IconProps | undefined; }'.
      Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
        Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type '(ReactChild & (string | number | boolean | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | ReactChild[] | null)) | undefined'.
```

Comment: I see in different tutorials that extending an interface it is possible to add more types that were not in the original interface. Thus it extends. The final interface will support more tipes (wider) not narrow. https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-extend-interface also in official documentation... https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: `the final interface will support more tipes (wider) not narrow.` Adding additional properties which were not mentioned in the original type makes the type *narrower*, not wider. If you don't mention a property, then it is compatible with any value. Once you mention it, you're restricted to just that value. Eg, an object compatible with `{ foo: string }` can have any value for `bar`, such as undefined, or a number. But once you do `{ foo: string, bar: string }`, bar can only be a string

Answer (score 1):

When you extend a type, you can only make it narrower, not wider. If you were allowed to make it wider, this would basically break subtyping. Consider this example:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

const someFunction = (person: Person) => {
  console.log(person.name.toUpperCase()); // Should be just fine: name is a string, strings have a toUpperCase property
}

const example: Person = {
  name: 'bob'
}
someFunction(example);
```

Now i want to extend from Person. Typescript will allow me to make it narrower, such as by limiting the name to specific strings. This extended type can be passed into someFunction, and someFunction will still work:

```
interface SpecificPerson extends Person {
  name: 'bob' | 'alice' | 'eve',
}
const example2: SpecificPerson = {
  name: 'alice'
}
someFunction(example2);
```

But if i was allowed to make things broader, then someFunction would break. No longer would name be a string, so when someFunction tries to call `.toUpperCase()`, an exception would be thrown

```
interface Entity extends Person {
  name: string | number; // Typescript won't actually let me do this
}
const example3: Entity = {
  name: 42,
}
someFunction(example3); // This shows a typescript error at compile time, and would throw a runtime error if it was allowed.
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3AQL4EEI601YUBiAVxAIwwHMgC8yABQAHTDmroo2EAEopAPnxFkXENgA2EAHRGsDeYpCnSFU2CwBVOQqgBhOBggz16pmQAeiDkAGUACyxBIwATZAAjFAArQR4YUCoSchRgDGQ4GjpGABoi+hAGfIi4ADcUQqdXdy8fZDkoLHcwAE82DgMeCAAPcjkTZRspXWJ7LIByBKwE+f7sAWFRcRAZEbGTAI5QSFhEFDCFBGAMhBU1ZBHIEFj8u4lCWZzqReX55AAfZDzOBGYBIP6A+YQerzEr9QZgB6jMjjCAAJmoFwgVxub1w0g+2Qo3xBYIgq3Y6wgQhEYhwu2RqLRhwIx2g8CQyAAouBgL0kU8XmgpoS5tRaBUGACSIIyEkoCx2AikfsIABmag8sT8gl6MXIAAsaLhlL41M2dJ2exRJjVASAA)

---

If you want a type that's similar to AccordionProps, but it swaps out children for a wider type, you can do that, but it will not be extending from AccordionProps. You won't be able to use it in places that expect AccordionProps:

```
type MultipleChildrenAccordionProps = Omit<AccordionProps, 'children'> & {
  children?: React.ReactChild[]|React.ReactNode|undefined;
}
```

Note that Accordion can not use this type. If accordion is implemented such that it only supports a single child, then you must give it a single child.

Depending on how Accordion is implemented, maybe you could pass it a fragment:

```
<StyledAccordion onChange={onChange}>
  <>
    <dt>Question(SBTi)?</dt>
    <div>answer </div>
    <dt>Question(SBTi)?</dt>
    <div>answer </div>
  </>
</StyledAccordion>
```

Or if that doesn't work, give it a div:

```
<StyledAccordion onChange={onChange}>
  <div>
    <dt>Question(SBTi)?</dt>
    <div>answer </div>
    <dt>Question(SBTi)?</dt>
    <div>answer </div>
  </div>
</StyledAccordion>
```

Comment: I've added it: `export const StyledAccordion = styled(Accordion)<MultipleChildrenAccordion>` ... however now on the component, in `<StyledAccordion onChange={onChange}>` it shows `No overload matches this call.` I'll update the original question with the whole error.

Comment: `export const StyledAccordion = styled(Accordion)<MultipleChildrenAccordion>` That will never work. If Accordion doesn't support multiple children, then it doesn't support multiple children. Using type assertions has the potential to shut typescript up at compile time, but you'll just end up getting errors at runtime. You will either need to pass a single child to Accordion, or change Accordion's source code so it supports multiple children (assuming you wrote it).